# Perform lookup in another table and produce selected results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am interested in "rendering" results of a `select` as a lookup in another table.

Given something like:

```
select [timestamp],[client_op]
from recording.dbo.events
```

`client_op` has a translation in a table `recording.dbo.EventTypes` and can be directly correlated to the column `OpCode` in `recording.dbo.EventTypes`.

I would like to return the value of the `EventName` which is contained in `recording.dbo.EventTypes` by using per `client_op` along with other results from `recording.dbo.events` only.  I basically want a straight replacement for `recording.dbo.events.client_op` with `recording.dbo.EventTypes.EventName`.

I've done research on `INNER JOIN` but am unable to figure out how to perform this type of lookup.

---

Here is the resolution as per the accepted answer below:

```
select C.[timestamp],C.[filer_id],C.[user_sid],C.[DirPath],C.[FileName],E.EventName
from varonis.dbo.cifs_events_2 C
join VrnsDomainDB.dbo.EventTypes E on C.[client_op]=E.OpCode
where C.[timestamp] >= dateadd( minute, -25, getdate() ) and ( charindex('.doc',C.[FileName]) > 0 or charindex('.xls',C.[FileName]) > 0 or charindex('.ppt',C.[FileName]) > 0 or charindex('.ont',C.[FileName]) > 0 ) order by C.USER_SID
```

Comment: Some table definitions and sample data along with desired results would make this question a LOT better. Here is a great place to get some ideas. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a straight-forward inner join to me:

```
select e.[timestamp],et.EventName
from recording.dbo.events e
join recording.dbo.EventTypes et on e.[client_op]=et.OpCode
```

Note that `join` is implicitly `inner`.

Comment: This seems like about the guess possible given the incredibly vague description.

Comment: Yeah, I think the description is basically a roundabout description of the concept of a join, written by someone who hasn't used one before.

Comment: Perfect!  I've updated the original question with the real world instance.